# Como modificar los valores de una columna con un filtro en power bi

Tags: powerbi

en mi power bi tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que cuando reaize una grafica, y tenga un filtro se modifique la columna de ranking. un ejemplo seria que cuando cambie el ranking y seleccione centro, me salga asi:

region |nro_trabajos|ranking

centro | 58         |1

centro | 59         |2

centro | 71         |3

.
.
etc

se puede realizar eso?

Comment: "quiero que cambie ranking" "y este es el ejemplo"... Nunca dijiste como quieres que cambie ranking, en estos casos lo mejor es crear otra columna calculada poniendole la lógica que quieres, pero si no nos dices la lógica no podemos adividarla a partir del ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Power Bi no tiene la posibilidad de ejecutar dinamicamente un código para columnas. Lo que puedes hacer es construir una Medida DAX (que si son dinámicas según las visualizaciones) con RANKX y utilizarla dentro de la tabla visual a mostrar.

Algo asi:

```
Medida_Ranking = RANKX(ALL('Tabla'[Region] ) ; SUM ( 'Tabla'[nro_trabajos] ) )
```

Espero que sirva

Comment: Podrias explicar como? mira por favor [answer]

Comment: Claro, ahi agrego a la respuesta la forma

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es visualizar esa tabla en tu dashboard y que la columna de ranking cambie dependiendo del contenido de tu tabla, yo probaría a insertar la visualización de tabla con los datos de las columnas región, nro_trabajos y ranking y añadir desde visualizaciones un filtro que filtre tus datos por el contenido de la columna región. De este modo si seleccionas como dices el campo Centro en el filtro, La tabla mostraría solo los campos Centro y como Ranking en principio entiendo que es una columna calculada con Dax, se ajustaría a los cambios.